# Search Bar Bringing A Blank Result Page

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x, bootstrapping

I am trying to build a search bar and this is the code in my view.py

```py
def searchjobs(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query = request.GET.get('q')

        submitbutton = request.GET.get('submit')

        if query is not None:
            lookups = Q(title_of_job__icontains = query) | Q(work_type__icontains = query) | Q(location__icontains = query) | Q(industry__icontains = query) | Q(job_function__icontains = query)

            results = Job.objects.filter(lookups).distinct()

            context = {'results': results, 'submitbutton': submitbutton}

            return render(request, 'job/search.html', context)

        else:
            return render(request, 'job/search.html')

    else:
        return render(request, 'job/search.html')
```

then for my search.html template, this is what I have

```
{% if submitbutton == 'Search' and request.GET.q != "" %}
    {% if results %}
    <h3>Results for <b>{{request.GET.q}}</b></h3><br/>

        {% for result in results %}

            <div class="container">
                <div class="card flex-row" style="box-shadow: 5px 5px lightgrey;">
                    <div>
                        <img class="rounded-circle card-img" src="{% static 'images/briefcase.png' %}">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4><a href="{% url 'job-detail' job.id %}" class="card-link">{{ job.title_of_job }}</a></h4>
                        <h5><a href="" class="card-link">{{ job.publisher }}</a></h5>
                        <h5 class="card-text">{{ job.location }} | {{ job.work_type }}</h5>
                        <h5><a href="" class="card-link">{{ job.job_function }}</a></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

when I run it in my browser, all I get is a blank page and not the things that is being put in the search bar. Please I will like some help. Thank you

Comment: If you install the django debug toolbar you can see the context being rendered for each template. Similarly, you could try rendering each of the context variables (submitbutton, request.GET, results) early in the template to verify they match what you expect to see.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work

Comment: you are looping with {% for result in results %} but why are you rendering with {{ job }}.
it should be {{result.publisher}}

Comment: I made the changes and yet, it was still blank